# Distance Matrix from second variable using get.shortest.paths()

Tags: r, routes, igraph

I would like to go one step further with this question ([Find total of second variable related to the distance of route from get.shortest.paths()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740100/find-total-of-second-variable-related-to-the-distance-of-route-from-get-shortest)). How does one get the matrix of distances between nodes, when the 'shortest' path is found using the newcost variable?

(My experience with igraph is very limited).

```
      df2 = rbind(c(234,235,21.6,75),
      c(234,326,11.0,35),
      c(235,241,14.5,78),
      c(326,241,8.2,98),
      c(241,245,15.3,75),
      c(234,245,38.46,65))

      df2 = as.data.frame(df2)
      names(df2) = c("start_id","end_id","newcost","distance")

      require(igraph)
      g2 <- graph.data.frame(df2, directed=FALSE)
      tmp2 = shortest.paths(g2,weights=E(g2)$newcost)
      tmp2 #this gives the matrix of newcost-weighted shortest distances
```

Where I could use help is how to find all paths, say using `optimal.path <- get.shortest.paths`, and using `sum(E(g2, path = optimal.path)$distance)` to create the matrix of distances

what I would really like is an edgelist of distances for all node pairs, like:

```
      startid endid shortestdist
      234     235     75
      234     245     208
```

What is tricky about this problem is that newcost is used to find the shortest paths, but what I want is the sum of another variable - the distance variable on each shortest path between node pairs.

Comment: So, you want all the data that's in `tmp2`, but you just want it in a different format? Instead of a matrix, you want rows for each start/end combination?

Comment: @MrFlick: Thanks for asking. What I want is different. The data in tmp2 is the 'newcost' sums, that gives the weighted path lengths. What I want is the sum of the distance variable for the shortest paths.

Comment: And those just happen to be equal for the two examples you've shown?

Comment: @MrFlick: the example has now been corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first let me make it clear that I am not an `igraph` user myself. Nevertheless I thought the question was interesting so I thought I'd take a look. And I too could find no easy solution to the problem you are having. I ended up making some helper functions to make the process possible. There is a good chance that i've re-coded the functionality inside `igraph` already but I could not find it.

Let me first define `get.shortest.paths.for.all` which will not just return the shortest path lengths for a given attribute, but will also return the shortest path themselves for all vertices in the graph. Here's that code

```
get.shortest.paths.for.all<-function(graph, attr) {
    paths<-lapply(1:(vcount(graph)-1), function(i) {
        get.all.shortest.paths(
            graph, 
            weights=get.edge.attribute(g2,attr),
            from = V(graph)[i],
            to = V(graph)[(i+1):vcount(graph)]
        )$res
    })
    unsplit(paths, rep.int(seq_along(paths), sapply(paths, length)))
}
```

Now let me define `get.path.dist.matrix` will takes a graph and a list of paths (like the one returned by `get.shortest.paths.for.all`) and will calculate the distance for a given attribute between each of those paths

```
get.path.dist.matrix<-function(graph, path, attr) {
    dd<-get.adjacency(graph, attr=attr)
    uniqs <- numeric(0)
    if (is.list(path)) {
        starts<-sapply(path, head, 1)
        ends<-sapply(path, tail, 1)
        uniqs <- unique(sort(c(starts,ends)))
    } else {
        uniqs <- c(head(path,1), tail(path,1))
    }
    m<-matrix(0, nrow=length(uniqs), ncol=length(uniqs),
        dimnames=list(V(graph)$name[uniqs],V(graph)$name[uniqs]))
    for(pp in path) {
        m[pp[1], pp[length(pp)]]<-sum(dd[embed(pp,2)])
    }
    m+t(m)
}
```

Using your sample data, I use them like this

```
paths <- get.shortest.paths.for.all(g2, "newcost")
get.path.dist.matrix(g2, paths,"distance")

#     234 235 326 241 245
# 234   0  75  35 133 208
# 235  75   0 176  78 153
# 326  35 176   0  98 173
# 241 133  78  98   0  75
# 245 208 153 173  75   0
```

Which seems reasonable and distinct from `shortest.paths(g2,weights=E(g2)$distance)`. To try to test my functions, I see that

```
all(tmp2==get.path.dist.matrix(g2, paths,"newcost"))
```

So feel free to try these out and let me know if you see any problems or possible improvements.